# executing programs with different languages

Tags: python, node.js, shell, raspberry-pi

Am doing my project in raspberry pi. I have written programs in python and also in node.js . I want to run these programs depending upon some conditions. And all these things should be done just by clicking in a single executable file. Can anyone help me out citing how it can be done? Can Shell Scripting satisfy my need?

Answer (score 0):

If you can determine that *some conditions* from shell script, then shell scripting can satisfy your need. That depends on what will be the condition.

As an alternative solution you can write another short program in node.js or python that will do the job.